# Android App Bottom Menu Bar using roughike API

Tags: android, android-menu, android-appbarlayout

I have implemented android bottom menu bar using roughike API

the icons in bottom menu bar is bit big and icon tile is wrap due to long icon tile.

I need to reduce icon and its title size in bottom menu bar.

so when I add style as follow, it is changing side menu bar and bottom menu bar as well. I want this style to be applied only for bottom menu bar not side menu bar
how do I achieve,

any expert advise/help

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item> 
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

for setting Title Style,Title Size And color :

```
<style name="BB_BottomBarItem_TitleStyle">
    <!-- Material spec: "Avoid long text labels as these labels do not truncate or wrap." -->
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>

<style name="BB_BottomBarItem_Fixed.TitleAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>

<style name="BB_BottomBarItem_Shifting.TitleAppearance" parent="BB_BottomBarItem_Fixed.TitleAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: since you are using roughike...you can directly use styles specified for bottommenu bar i don't understand why are you going for customized android theme seperately??

Comment: i need to apply style for bottom bar

Comment: @user1439582 HV you implemented this lines in your code..??is there any error..after implementing this??..

Comment: sorry. can you help me with calling the style in the code. what method should i use. i once tried. bottobar.setFace(). that failed

Comment: the reason why i want to apply style for bottom bar is that the icon tile it bit long so it shows in wrap on the android home page.due to text wrap, the icons with title occupy more space in the bottom of the home page